# How to give name to each element of cell?

Tags: matlab

I have created a cell like follow:
My_cell=cell(1,20) and I have stored in every part of this cell a matrix.
like this :

```
My_cell(1,10)=My_matrix
```

Now I want to give name to each element of this cell such that, later on I can figure out which matrix is stroed in every position of cell.
Would someone help me withis? I'm quite new in Matlab

Comment: What's wrong with calling it `My_cell(1,10)`?

Comment: I'm doing lot's of downstream processing and alaysis, so if I know the name of matrix, will make analysis easy!! ;)

Comment: Then a cell is probably the wrong data structure because it does not support names. Take a look at `table` or `struct`

Comment: You're leaving out a lot of details about how these matrices are related, what kind of data they contain, and how they will be used. But "naming" each matrix is simply asking for headaches.

Comment: If you're new to matlab, then perhaps "naming" the matrix isn't what you want to do. What is it that you *really* want to achieve with your cell array of matrices? There might be a better way to do things.

Comment: make a struct which holds the name and the matrix, and store the structs into your cell array.

Comment: As others have said, you could use a struct for the names. The other option is to make a separate cell array storing the names.